# How to get drop downlist selected item from view and pass it to model(future purpose)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have got a drop downlist that, and i need to set the selected value in a view ,later on when the user selected any item in drop down list , i need to pass that one to model.. I am binding dropdown list in  controller like this way ..

```
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var itemsforDropdown = new List<SelectListItem> {             
               new SelectListItem{ Text = "Amount" , Value = "Amount"},
               new   SelectListItem{Text= "Pound", Value ="Pound"},
                new  SelectListItem {Text ="Percent", Value ="Percent"}            
            };
            ViewBag.ItemsforDrop = itemsforDropdown;
            //ViewData["listitem"] = itemsforDropdown;
            return View("DdlCrossFields");
        }
```

and I have got a property in my model like this...

```
public class CrossFieldValidation
{
    [ValueMustbeInRange]
    public string DDlList1
    { get; set; }

    public string SelectedValue
    { get; set; }

    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]

    [Display(Name = "Quantity:")]
    public string TxtCrossField
    { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view ...

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes"))
  {   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>
      @Html.DropDownList("ItemsforDrop", ViewBag.ItemsforDrop as SelectList,"Select A state", new {id= "State"})  
    //here i need to get  the selected value and i need to pass the this on to model fro future purpose " 
    <input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
   }
```

would any one pls help on this ...
many thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding it hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to achieve here but I would set up the page like below.

This way, the `CrossFieldValidation` is sent to the `PostValues` with the selected value in the list

**Model**

```
public class CrossFieldValidation
{
    [ValueMustbeInRange]
    public string DDlList1
    { get; set; }

    /* add the items list into the model */
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items 
    { get; set; }    

    public string SelectedValue
    { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantity:")]
    public string TxtCrossField
    { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CrossFieldValidation {
        Items = new [] {             
           new SelectListItem{ Text = "Amount" , Value = "Amount"},
           new SelectListItem{Text= "Pound", Value ="Pound"},
           new SelectListItem {Text ="Percent", Value ="Percent"}            
        }
    };     

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
 @model CrossFieldValidation
 @using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes"))
  {   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"))  

    <input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller [HttpPost] action add below.

```
string selectedVal = Request.Form["ItemsforDrop"].ToString();
```